# Error: The name AuthenticationState does not exist in the current context

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-authentication, xamarin.auth

I am doing google signin for my project . I am getting this error: 'The name AuthenticationState does not exist in the current context' in the MainActivity.cs page .Please see the attached screenshot. will it be removed by adding some nuget packages? i have added only xamarin.auth package. How to solve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while following the steps at [Authenticating Users with an Identity Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth). That page doesn't make it clear at all what you're supposed to do here.

The `AuthenticationState` class is a class in the [sample project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/OAuthNativeFlow) that has a reference to the authenticator. The authenticator is an instance of `OAuth2Authenticator` that you might have created as a local variable in the method where you are starting the login flow. Since that same authenticator is needed when your app is re-launched after the login flow has finished, it's better to add it as a static property to another class that can be used by both the login flow and when your app is re-launched.

For example, the `AuthenticationState` class could look something like this:

```
public class AuthenticationState
{
    public static OAuth2Authenticator Authenticator { get; } =
        new OAuth2Authenticator(clientId, clientSecret, scopes,
            new Uri(authorizeUrl), new Uri(redirectUrl),
            new Uri(tokenUrl), null, true);
}
```

Replace the parameters to the `OAuth2Authenticator` constructor based on the remote service you're connecting to.